VBA: Strange behavior with Int function
I am wondering about this behavior that I see in VBA. I am using the Immediate console to debug my code and got the following result:
Debug.Print(Int(0.00024575*10000000+0.5))
 2457

I would expect this result to be 2458. Does anyone know why this is occurring? As expected, before the Int function is called, the calculation is in Double precision.
Debug.Print(VarType(0.00024575*10000000+0.5))
 5 

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I'd guess floating-point error.

Shouldn't Int properly deal with doubles, though? This is bad behavior for such a widely used language like VBA.

@BigBen Sorry, I just meant this is surprising behavior, even for a function that just truncates. I would think it would output a more reliable result, but it doesn't seem very robust... I would expect floating point-errors at higher input precision.

If you run the following test:
Sub Test()
    Dim d As Double: d = 0.5 + 0.00024575 * 10000000
    
    Debug.Assert d = Int(d)
    Debug.Assert 0.5 + 2457.5 = Int(0.5 + 2457.5)
    Debug.Assert 0.5 + 0.00024575 * 10000000 = Int(CDbl(0.5 + 0.00024575 * 10000000))
    Debug.Assert 0.5 + 0.00024575 * 10000000 = CDbl(0.5 + 0.00024575 * 10000000)
    Debug.Assert 0.5 + 0.00024575 * 10000000 = VBA.Int(0.5 + 0.00024575 * 10000000)
    Debug.Assert 0.5 + 0.00024575 * 10000000 = Int(0.5 + 0.00024575 * 10000000)
End Sub

You will see that only the last Assert fails. This is probably a compiler bug.
Note that Int is not the same as VBA.Int.
Edit #1
As suggested in the comments by @GSerg, it appears that the Int method (not VBA.Int) does indeed calculate at compile time and it probably uses a different floating point precision. For example:
Option Explicit

#Const Test = Int(12.5)

Sub TestPrecompiler()
    #If Test = 12 Then
        Debug.Print "Int method calculates at compile time"
    #End If
End Sub


Very interesting, good find.

So Int is also a funny function like Len? But it's not a keyword, nor do I see a reason for it to be. It's as if the entire Int(0.5 + 0.00024575 * 10000000) is calculated at compile time (which it can be in case of the funny functions), and the compiler uses different floating point precision at that point (which is not unusual), whereas everything else is processed at runtime.

@GSerg Indeed. If I remember correctly, Int can be used in compiler constants but I am away from my PC to test it

Nope, says Constant expression required.

@GSerg good refs, thanks!

@GSerg #Const Test = Int(12.5) compiles fine for me. I am using Office 365 Excel on Win x64 VBA7

So it works in a compilation constant. It doesn't in regular constants though. And then Int is not special, many others also work in compilation constants but not regular ones.
